# Can you access the Koa Context from an Express Req object?

Tags: koa, koa2

A part of our code only has access to the Node/Express `req` object.

However, we need to access the Koa Request and/or Koa Context.

Does Koa inject the Context into the Node `req` object at all?

---

(Additional context: we're using Koa Multer together with S3 Multer, and S3 Multer only provides `req` in its callbacks, since it was obviously designed for the original Multer library.)

Comment: AFAIK it’s the other way around, and it’d be circular to have the context in the req contained in the context. *You* could add it, but I wouldn’t—it’d be safer and cleaner to add the *portion* of the context you need—or update your code to be Koa-esque.

Comment: I believe there's already a circular graph between the Koa request and the Koa context: `ctx.Request.ctx.Request.ctx..` That in itself is not a bad thing (as it's not like anyone's trying to serialize request objects :D). Making the code Koa-esque would be great, but unfortunately, we're being held by a third-party library (Multer S3).

Comment: The `multer-s3` that's 250 lines of code? :shrug: IMO you're thinking about this backwards--make your code Koa-esque--doesn't seem like making an `multer-s3` that does what you want would be traumatic. I'd note again that nothing prevents you from adding the Koa context to the NodeJS `req` via a middleware/etc.

Comment: A fork of `multer-s3` is probably the best way to go, just given we've had to bend our code in other ways to deal with its callback API (which splits metadata and S3 location into two). Thanks for adjusting our course :)

Comment: It's probably worth a PR against multer-s3 to support Koa, or a public koa-multer-s3 since this may be of general use :thumbs-up: